# How can I test, whether my deployed background server application on AWS beanstalk gets messages through a socketstream with an android mobile client?

Tags: sockets, amazon-web-services, chat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The overall topic is actually like a **Chat Application** sending a simple string message to an aws server, which uses the message to make calculations server-side and sending a simple string message as a solution back to the client.

**Server:** I have written a Server Class and deployed it through eclipse to aws beanstalk. *(see code Server)*

**Client:** My android device creates a socket, establishes a successful connection to my aws beanstalk ip and 8080 port, while iterating through an endless while loop in a thread listening to incoming messages from the server. *(see code Client and ClientThread)*

**Problem:** My problem is that I don't know how to check whether the server receives the connection request and messages from the client. How do I make sure, that code on aws beanstalk actually runs in background continuously listening for incoming connections? I have deployed the code, does aws beanstalk automatically start the main method of the Server Class and runs it infinitely?

Here's the server code:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    ServerSocket server = null;
    System.out.println("Trying to open serversocket!");
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(8080);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error on port: 8080 " + ", " + e);
        System.exit(1);
    }

    System.out
            .println("Server setup and waiting for client connection ...");

    Socket client = null;
    try {
        client = server.accept();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Did not accept connection: " + e);
        System.exit(1);
    }

    System.out
            .println("Client connection accepted. Moving to local port ...");

    try {
        DataInputStream streamIn = new DataInputStream(
                new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream streamOut = new DataOutputStream(
                new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream()));

        boolean done = false;
        String line;
        int i = 4;
        while (!done) {

            line = streamIn.readUTF();
            if (line.equalsIgnoreCase(".bye"))
                done = true;
            else
                System.out.println("Client says: " + line);
            if (i == 4) {
                streamOut
                        .writeUTF("Actually connected to Server with round "
                                + i);
                streamOut.flush();
                i++;
            }

        }

        streamIn.close();
        streamOut.close();
        client.close();
        server.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO Error in streams " + e);
    }
}
}
```

Here's the client code:

```
package com.amazon.aws.singlesensor;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.util.Log;

class Client implements Runnable {
    private Socket socket = null;
private InputStream streamIn = null;
private OutputStream streamOut = null;

public InputStream getStreamIn() {
    return streamIn;
}

public Client(String serverName, int serverPort) {
    System.out.println("Establishing connection. Please wait ...");
    try {
        socket = new Socket(serverName, serverPort);
        Log.d("DEBUG", "Connected: " + socket);
        start();
    } catch (UnknownHostException uhe) {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "Host unknown: " + uhe.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "Unexpected exception: " + ioe.getMessage());
    }

}

public void start() throws IOException {
    streamIn = socket.getInputStream();
    streamOut = socket.getOutputStream();

}

public void run() {

    try {
        streamOut.write(streamIn.read());
        streamOut.flush();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Sending error: " + ioe.getMessage());
        stop();
    }

}

public void handle(String msg) {
    if (msg.equals(".bye")) {
        System.out.println("Good bye. Press RETURN to exit ...");
        stop();
    } else
        System.out.println(msg);
}

public void stop() {

    try {
        if (streamIn != null)
            streamIn.close();
        if (streamOut != null)
            streamOut.close();
        if (socket != null)
            socket.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Error closing ...");
    }

}

public void send(String msg) {
    PrintWriter printwriter = new PrintWriter(streamOut);
    printwriter.write(msg);
    printwriter.flush();
}

}
```

Here's the ClientThread Code

```
 package com.amazon.aws.singlesensor;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;

 import android.os.Handler;

 public class ClientThread extends Thread {

private Client client;
private InputStream input;
private String output;
private Handler handler;
private Runnable runner;

public ClientThread() {

}

public ClientThread(Client client, Handler handler, Runnable runner) {

    this.setClient(client);
    this.input = client.getStreamIn();
    this.handler = handler;
    this.runner = runner;
    this.output = "";

}

public void run() {

    int status = 0;
    while (status != -1) {

        try {
            status = input.read();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (status != '~'){
            try {
                status = input.read();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            output = output + String.valueOf((char) status);

            handler.post(runner);
        }
        output = output + "\n";



    }

}

public String giveString(){
    return output;
}

public void setClient(Client client) {
    this.client = client;
}

public Client getClient() {
    return client;
}

 }
```

**Thank you for your time!**